# d3, html in svg, animating opacity takes div out of position, why?

Tags: html, svg, d3.js, position

**Some context:**

I've made a force layout, and I've attached divs to my svg g nodes, so that I can display nice paragraphs of text.
I'm trying to create transitions that fade out the inserted divs.

**The problem:**

Whenever I initiate a transition on the opacity style attribute of my div, it pops out of the positioning flow. I've isolated the issue in the linked [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ29K/). It's not related to the force layout, but I am using the foreign elements so that I can place html in a svg-based force layout.

here's an example, and [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ29K/):

```
var foreign = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("width", 300)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(40, 20)")
    .append("svg:foreignObject")
    .attr("width", "100px")
    .attr("height", "50px");

var outer = foreign.append("xhtml:div")
    .attr("class", "outer");

var inner = outer.append("xhtml:div")
    .attr("class", "inner")
    .text("inner div");

outer.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .style("opacity", 0.0);
```

And a screenshot visual, from the fiddle (note how it seems to duplicate the div)

state right before transition:

[image]

state during transition:

[image]

I'm using Chrome 28 on OS X 10.6.8 to view it. It gets even funkier on Safari, with elements flashing in and out of visibility.

Comment: Could you post an example with the force layout that shows the problem please?

Comment: I've isolated the issue in the fiddle, and it appears unrelated to the force layout, (which I'm just using to adjust the translate attributes of my g elements) I just wanted to give some context on why I was using foreignObjects. But yeah, I'll pull that out.

Comment: Hmm, your fiddle works fine for me. Chromium on Linux.

Comment: darn, that makes it harder to understand & fix. It looks consistently like the screenshot for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem still does not seem to be fixed on Google Chrome (v49.0.2623.110).
Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abaland/nvjso049/) still showing the issue for me.

```
<svg width="500">
  <g transform="translate(0,50)">
    <foreignObject width="500" height="200">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" value="A" style="opacity: 0.9;">
        <input type="text" value="B" style="opacity: 1;">
      </fieldset>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Seems the combination of 'g:translate' and 'foreignObject' is not well handled with webkit browsers. Apparently, "transferring" the vertical/horizontal shift from the 'g:translate' to the 'x' or 'y' tags of the foreign objects fix the problem. Proof [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abaland/soLgee56/).

```
<svg width="500">
  <g>
    <foreignObject width="500" height="200" y="50">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" value="A" style="opacity: 0.9;">
        <input type="text" value="B" style="opacity: 1;">
      </fieldset>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't seem to understand *why* the opacity transition moves the div out of position. Perhaps it's a bug that has since been solved, since Lars saw no problems on Chromium.

However I did find a solution to the issue of animating my divs within the svg: wrap the foreignObject in it's own svg:g element and animate the g element, not the div inside the foreignObject.

Here's [an edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZ662/1/) that works on both Chrome 28 and Safari 5.1.9 for me on OS X 10.6.8.

And the difference in the code:

```
var gWrapOnForeign = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("width", 300)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(40, 20)")
    .append("svg:g");

var foreign = gWrapOnForeign.append("svg:foreignObject")
    .attr("width", "100px")
    .attr("height", "50px");

var outer = foreign.append("xhtml:div")
    .attr("class", "outer")
    .style("opacity", 1.0);

var inner = outer.append("xhtml:div")
    .attr("class", "inner")
    .text("inner div");

gWrapOnForeign.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .style("opacity", 0.0);
```